# Firefox Addon: Load URI Event

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

In a Firefox Addon I delegate the User to a new URL through

```
window.content.wrappedJSObject.location = 'http://newlocation/';
```

What I am asking for is a `load event` binding for the site-change. I tried

```
window.content.addEventListener('load', function() { });
```

.. which won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this example cover what you want: [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load) ?

If not, you have to specify further what you mean.

Comment: Your link and [Intercepting Page Loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads) helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually look at the error messages. Ctrl-shift-J is your friend! In this case `addEventListener` requires a 3rd boolean parameter: `window.content.addEventListener('load', function() { }, true);` or `window.content.addEventListener('load', function() { }, false);`. This indicates whether you want the listener to be called during the bubbling phase or the capture phase. In most cases, it doesn't matter which one you use, except (IIRC) the `load` event doesn't bubble so you have to use the capturing phase (`true`).